# Formulas applied to extracted values return #VALUE! in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm extracting some log data from an internal service to excel and need to apply some basic formulas on the numeric values in the extract. The numeric values do not allow calculations against them (e.g. Column A + C)) and instead return #VALUE!. Within the same sheet, I can however manually add data and these values are calculable. I've tried a number of formatting ideas to try and fix the issue to no avail.

I've tried:

- Copy "1", Paste special, "Multiply" on all values
- Change format to / from General to Number and back again
- use TRIM to remove spaces
- Use Find and Replace to remove spaces in front / behind values
- Resaved the file from CSV to .xlsx
- Confirmed / tested "calculate now" was set to automatic
- Confirmed calculations are allowed on the sheet by manually adding values and applying formulas against them.
- I've also dug into Trust Center settings and Formula settings and find no smoking gun.

I consider myself an advanced user of MS Excel so not being able to solve this is a bit frustrating. Appreciate the help.

Comment: #VALUE error usually means you are *mixing* incorrect data types. If you do 2+1 Excel will return 3 but if you do 2+"Spiderman" Excel will return #VALUE because you are mixing text with numeric values. Can you post a data example? Looks like your numeric values are not being recognized as numbers.

Comment: Column A (extracted data) - 110.78
Column B (Manually entered data) - 141

110.78 + 141 = #VALUE!

I've just run a character count on the extracted cell and see that 110.78 shows 7 characters, even after "TRIM" and Find and Replace. I've clicked on the value and pressed "delete" for a few seconds, and now character count shows 6 and I can calculate on the value. 

I don't see any character or symbol or space to give me the extra character. Now the question is, how to completely remove all non-numeric values from a cell?

Comment: Very annoying. If I use the CLEAN function on the cell, I can remove the hidden, non-printable value to fix the issue. I need to go back to the team and let them know of this new issue on our extract data. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Please, check [CLEAN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41). Let's say A1= 110.78 (extracted data) and B1=141 (manually). On C1 try `CLEAN(A1)+B1`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using Excels "CLEAN" function to remove all non-printable characters from the cell. I validated the issue by using "LEN" to count characters and found an extra, non-visible character. After using "CLEAN" to remove the hidden character, I was able to apply formulas against the data.